# Dnn Persona Bar missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetnuke

I am working in DNN 9 for some reason the PersonaBar is no longer showing up. I am getting the error below.

jquery.js?cdv=48:4 GET http://localhost:53857/API/personaBar/localization/gettable?culture=en-US 404 (Not Found)

I have already check newtonSoft.json and it is pointing to 7.0.0

Logs:

DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.LocalizationProvider - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.get_Status()
   at DotNetNuke.Services.Localization.LocalizationProvider.TryGetStringInternal(String key, String userLanguage, String resourceFile, PortalSettings portalSettings, String& resourceValue)
DotNetNuke.Common.Internal.ServicesRoutingManager - Unable to register service routes
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Http, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
   at DotNetNuke.Web.Api.Internal.ServicesRoutingManager.RegisterRoutes()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at DotNetNuke.Common.Internal.ServicesRoutingManager.RegisterServiceRoutes()

Issue Resolved. System.Web.Http some how got deleted.

Comment: Was this an upgrade from an older version?  Also, do you see anything in the logs (/Portals/_default/Logs) related to the error?

Comment: Hi, no this was a fresh install and a custom module and skin. I've edited the question with the log info.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to System.Web.Http being missing from the project. I resolved this issue by updating references.

This is pretty close, I had to update my web.config and corresponding dlls in Bin folder for persona bar to start working.

Answer (score 0):

Restoring the bin folder could be a posibility here.